# How to concatenate a Swift dictionary to Firestore map field

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to concatenate a swift dictionary <String,String> inside a firestore map field. I've tried multiple ways like FieldValue.arrayUnion as I saw in previous posts but it isn't working. Is there any straightforward way to do it?

```
//users is the collection and watched is the map field in firestore that I want to update with the dictionary {stringA : stringB}
db.collection("users").document(self.userID).updateData(["watched": {stringA:stringB}])
```

I want to add that it works for me when adding the dictionary to an array field. However, it does present a problem of duplication and ease of referencing. Since Firestore has a map type field, I was wondering if there's any method to directly concatenate a swift dictionary as key value pair, as shown on the second picture (done manually).
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in Firestore are great if you only have 1 value to store. Since you're trying to store a dictionary, I would suggest creating a sub-collection. The logic for creating a sub-collection is the exact same as creating a regular collection (ie. Users) except the path will begin within a document of a parent collection.

Within the user's document create a sub-collection called "watched" and within the sub-collection you could add documents and set the documentID equal to stringA. This also allows you to query on the watched collection (for example if you need to see if a user watched a specific stringA).

The collection path would be something like:

```
db.collection("users").document(self.userID).collection("watched").document(stringA)
```

Within the new document, you would store stringB and other data, something like:

```
let data: [String:Any] = [
     document_id : stringA, // optional
     watch_time : stringB,
]
```

Side note: Firestore does support storing Numbers directly. Based on the image you posted, it looks like stringB is a Number and you're storing it as a String in the database. I would try to avoid switching Types whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response @nicksarno. I'm trying to create a sub collection using the following code and while it does work, it creates a new document every time. replacing this with your answer and using updateData didn't make any changes to the database so is there a way to create a document and add values to only that document?  db.collection("users").document(self.userID).collection("watchCollection").addDocument(data: [stringA: StringB])

Comment: When you call .addDocument it will create an autogenerated documentID. You can just update a specific document by instead calling .document(stringA). Firebase has really good documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Thanks nick, it worked when I used setData! `db.collection("users").document(self.userID).collection("watchedCollection").document("StringA").setData([valA: valB], merge: true)`